# How to delete table on Cassandra using C# Datastax driver?

Tags: c#, cassandra, datastax

```
var keyspace = "mydb";
var datacentersReplicationFactors = new Dictionary<string, int>(0);
var replication = ReplicationStrategies.CreateNetworkTopologyStrategyReplicationProperty(datacentersReplicationFactors);

using (var cluster = Cluster.Builder().AddContactPoints("my_ip").Build())
using (var session = cluster.Connect())
{
    session.CreateKeyspaceIfNotExists(keyspace, replication, true);
    session.ChangeKeyspace(keyspace);

    var entityTable = new Table<Models.Entity>(session);
    var attributeTable = new Table<Models.Attribute>(session);

    entityTable.CreateIfNotExists(); // Worked
    attributeTable.CreateIfNotExists(); // Worked

    entityTable.Delete(); // Does nothing
    attributeTable.Delete();  // Does nothing
}
```

**EDIT:** Without using raw queries `session.Execute("DROP TABLE entities;");` working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless there is already a method for dropping tables that I not aware of, you can use this extensions.

```
public static class DastaxTableExtensions
{
    public static void Drop<T>(this Table<T> table)
    {
        table.GetSession().Execute($"DROP TABLE {table.Name};");
    }

    public static void DropIfExists<T>(this Table<T> table)
    {
        table.GetSession().Execute($"DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {table.Name};");
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like this

```
entityTable.Drop();
attributeTable.DropIfExists();
```

Answer (score 4):

`Delete()` method is not intended for drop of the tables. It returns representation of a DELETE cql statement. If you call it, you just get `{DELETE FROM entities}`.

If you need to drop a table, the easiest way is just to execute DROP statement:

```
session.Execute("DROP TABLE entities;");
```

Comment: I getting "line 0:-1 mismatched input '<EOF>' expecting K_WHERE"

Comment: What query is returned by Delete()?

Comment: Hmm it seems this is the DELETE command and not the DROP, I getting  `{DELETE FROM entities}`

Comment: Seems so. When I need to drop some table I'm using direct DROP execution as you specified in your edit.

Comment: okay thanks, I will do an extension then and will post it here.